# need to connect my same apps with one database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-dynamodb

i have 3 servers for three applications on aws ec2 using MySql database,
now each of the application is having amember that is client subscription app,
it connects with sql databse that is created in each instance 
so in this way every amamber app is having diffrent database in each server,
now we are working with a device ROKU we need to pass the XML attributes from amember to it 
to varify the user so he can watch online streaming tv.

the objective
now i need to make one database that will be connected with each server using amember 
so each server access one database .

Options

my options are aws RDS ,dynamoDb

Now can anyone put me in the right direction, for that.

in simple Words
need to connect my multiple apps (same app) with one database
 HELLLLP

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect to a mysql database, DynamoDB is not the answer. It isn't a mysql database.

RDS is a mysql database. It connects like any other mysql database. You haven't mentioned what language[s] you are using, however. Googling "connect to mysql with [language]" should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to stick with relational databases such as MySQL.
Amazon RDS is a managed MySQL solution, but you don't have to use it for your needs.
You can use one of your EC2 instances or a new EC2 instance as the central DB and connect all the other servers to it for quires. There are pros and cons for choosing RDS over your own SQL server. If you have any questions there, feel free to edit your question and add them.

EDIT according to comment
In order to connect your application with the local MySQL. Your are probably using a connection string that points to either "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"... That is the IP of your local machine. You will have to change it to the remote IP of the machine where the DB is stored remotely.

Comment: thanks Chen but can you give me littel more on that, like if i have created an instance name ABC (its DB) and i want to point my application on XYZ instance to ABC localhost, then how should i tell my application to connect db remotly,